# Antialias the view being transformed

Tags: android, transform, antialiasing

I am transforming child views in my viewgroup when I'm swiping through the viewgroup (kind of a cover-flow effect). I am using `matrix.setPolyToPoly` for transformation. The views have borders which need antialiasing severely.

So far I've tried to use

```
canvas.setDrawFilter(new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(0, Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG));
```

in my children's `onDraw`, but it doesn't seem to change anything. Also, I'm aware of `BitmapDrawable.setAntiAlias(true)`, but my children are not drawables, but full-blown viewgroups with views inside, so I cannot use that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Override

```
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
```

in  your custom layout and set filter there.

```
    canvas.setDrawFilter(new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(1, Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG));
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
```

I encountered a similar issue in my cover flow inspired Gallery. This solved my issue.